# Nested preloading in Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to write a nested query in ecto which preloads `comments` from the post table and then in a separate query I am preloading the `user` for each comment. This looks like:

```
post = Repo.preload(Repo.get(Post, id), [:comments])
comments = Repo.preload(post.comments, [:user])
```

The problem with this is that it runs 3 different queries on the database when I know there is a way to load all the data I need in one query.

Is it something to do with `join: assoc()`?

Comment: Do you expect _this exact code_ to only run one query? Or are you looking for another way to do that that would require just one query? In the former case it seems impossible - you're making three separate calls to functions that perform a query.

Comment: I am looking for another way to do the same thing as that code but in one query. So it would end up like `post = Repo.one(new_query)`

Answer (score 1):

*(I put a late answer here just for my own reference.)* You may try this:

```
Repo.preload(Repo.get(Post, id), [{:comments, :user}]).comments
```

or equivalently, either of the followings:

```
Repo.preload(Repo.get(Post, id), [comments: :user]).comments
Repo.preload(Repo.get(Post, id), comments: :user).comments
```

[This blog post by tkowal](https://tkowal.wordpress.com/2016/04/23/nested-preload-in-ecto/) has an excellent explanation of the syntax for constructing nested preloads. [This discussion between José Valim and a netizen](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/1051) is also useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do that with one query, as far as I know, you would have to join the comments and users to the post and if there are, let's say, 50 comments, you would have 50 rows with the same user in it and I don't don't know if that's ok for you. I think you could do that with 2 queries though, it would be something like this:

```
comments_query = 
  Comment
  |> join(:inner, [c], u in assoc(c, :user))
  |> preload([c, u], user: u)
post = Repo.preload(Repo.get(Post, id), comments: comments_query)
```

I have not tested the code but I believe it should work or at least you get the general idea.